# How to read docker port mapping information?

Tags: mysql, docker, port

I just started learning docker and I‘m a bit confused with port mapping in docker. I have container (which runs mysql service) running as below:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS

59efytd163d3        myapp:mysql         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 months ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:9991->3306/tcp
```

For the `PORTS` field, what does `0.0.0.0:9991->3306/tcp` mean?

I checked the port number of mysql that's running outside the container:

```
john@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents$ lsof -n -P -i TCP | grep mysql
mysqld     1742 john   58u  IPv4 0xd3c7de51ef6d2a49      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)
```

As you can see, the port is 3306, so  I thought the port number for the mysql running inside the container must be 9991. However, after I got into the container and checked the mysql:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT'
    -> ;
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It also shows 3306.

Both the mysql services running inside and outside the container has port number 3306. Where does the `0.0.0.0:9991->3306/tcp` mean then? what does the `0.0.0.0:9991` refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker runs containers on virtual networks:

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                 DRIVER              SCOPE
1234567890ab        bridge               bridge              local
cdef01234567        deployment_default   bridge              local
890abcdef012        host                 host                local
34567890abcd        none                 null                local
```

These port mappings bind ports on your host machine with containers running on these networks.

Think of each container as its own localhost with all ports available to it. In this case, your MySQL instance exposes port `3306` on its container. This is necessary because the binary in the container is also running on `3306`. This explains why, within the container, you see `3306`.

Very conveniently, when you run a container, Docker provides a mechanism for you to remap container ports (e.g. `3306`) onto different ports (e.g. `9991`) on your host machine.

This is more than just a convenience. If you wanted to run a second MySQL container image and it was also configured for `3306`, you'd be unable to access both containers at the same time because they'd collide with the port `3306` on your host.

So, you define a port-mapping as you've done. In your example, from your local workstation (host), you can access the MySQL container instance on `localhost:9991` and Docker remaps that port's traffic to the MySQL container's port `3306` and the container routes it to the MySQL binary (also on `3306`).

So: `0.0.0.0:9991->3306/tcp` means:

- `0.0.0.0` (an alias for any adaptor on `localhost`)
- `9991` port traffic maps to this container's port `3306`
- Using TCP (another protocol that you will see is `UDP`)

Three additional notes:

- This image's Dockerfile may include e.g. `EXPOSE 3306`. This is purely documentary and in no way affects the `docker run ... --publish=XXXX/3306..` command.
- Container needs not publish ports to the localhost. This need only be done if the container image must be accessed from the host. If you name your containers and put them on user-defined networks or use Docker Compose, one container may access ports on another container *without* exposing ports to the host. Exposing ports like this should be (!) a security consideration.
- When you run a container image, Docker uses a default network. The port-mapping resolution (`0.0.0.0:XXXX/YYYY`) is actually a combination of identifying which container (hostname resolution) and which port.